# Plotting spherical harmonics in matlab

Tags: matlab, computer-vision, opticalflow

i want to plot spherical harmonics of zero order in Cartesian Coordinates, but output from Matlab is different is not sphere.

```
x11 = linspace(-1,1,100);
x22 = linspace(-1,1,100);
x33 = linspace(-1,1,100);

[x1 ,x2, x3]= meshgrid(x11,x22,x33);

G = (exp((-1)*(x1.^2 + x2.^2 + x3.^2)));
isosurface(G);
```

can someone suggest where i am wrong and if possible give me how to plot higher order spherical harmonics. Thank you.

Comment: I'm not perfectly sure, but don't you want `linspace` instead of `logspace`?

Comment: I agree with @knedlsepp, you should use `linspace` to cover a cube of of extend [-1,1] along x,y,z axes. Moreover in `isosurface`, you have to indicate for the `isovalue` at which you wanna plot things so `isosurface(x1, x2, x3, G, 0.5)` for instance (i.e. plots the isosurface where G == 0.5)

Comment: For higher order, I truly advice you to buy the blue book ([Hansen](http://books.google.fr/books?id=x1IFmCaymNQC&printsec=frontcover&hl=fr#v=onepage&q&f=false)) as a *must have* reference. See in appendix *A.1.2* for a formulation directly in spherical coordinates *(isosurface)* and for recurrence formulas. I'm unfortunately not allowed to provide you my implementation in matlab, anyhow there are many code around (e.g. on [fileexchange](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/8638-spherical-harmonics)).

Comment: Could it be it doesn't *look* like a sphere? Sometimes plots distort appearances because different dims are scaled differently on screen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, I would not advice you to work from evaluating spherical harmonics for all possible coordinates within a cube and then use `isosurface` to plot things (I even think that you're misinterpreting `isosurface` as cutting data at some constant radius (which is absolutely not the case, see [documentation](http://fr.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/isosurface.html)).

Best to draw spherical harmonics, is to use their formulation in spherical coordinates `(r, phi, theta)`. You can find some of these formulations for a few modes [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Table_of_spherical_harmonics). Formulas are only provided for the angular part, the radial part depends on your domain.

Taking for instance `l=1`, `m=-1` you can generate this harmonic on a (azimuth, elevation) grid like this:

```
azimuths = linspace(0, 360, 361) * pi / 180;
elevations = linspace(0, 180, 181) * pi / 180;

[A, E] = ndgrid(azimuths, elevations);
H = 0.25 * sqrt(15/(2*pi)) .* exp(-1j*A) .* sin(E) .* cos(E);
```

You can then transform the grid back to cartesian grid like this:

```
X = cos(A) .* sin(E);
Y = sin(A) .* sin(E);
Z = cos(E);
```

You can also add some radial distortion to make things look nicer:

```
Data = abs(imag(H));
minData = min(Data(:));
maxData = max(Data(:));
Distord = (Data - minData)/(maxData-minData);

X = Distord .* cos(A) .* sin(E);
Y = Distord .* sin(A) .* sin(E);
Z = Distord .* cos(E);

surf(X, Y, Z, Data);
shading flat;
```

Which gives:

[image: SphericalHarmonic(l=1,m=-1)]

Answer (score 4):

Use MATLAB's spherical harmonics function

```
degree=6;
order=0;
grid=40;
radius=5;

% Create the grid
delta = pi/grid;
theta = 0 : delta : pi; % altitude
phi = 0 : 2*delta : 2*pi; % azimuth
[phi,theta] = meshgrid(phi,theta)

% Calculate the harmonic
Ymn = legendre(degree,cos(theta(:,1)))
Ymn = Ymn(order+1,:)';
yy = Ymn;
for kk = 2: size(theta,1);
    yy = [yy Ymn]
end;
yy = yy.*cos(order*phi);

order = max(max(abs(yy)));
rho = radius + 2*yy/order;

% Apply spherical coordinate equations
r = rho.*sin(theta);
x = r.*cos(phi);  % spherical coordinate equations
y = r.*sin(phi);
z = rho.*cos(theta);

% Plot the surface
clf
surf(x,y,z)
light
lighting phong
axis tight equal off
view(40,30)
camzoom(1.5)
```

Which gives:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Add `axis equal` to the bottom of your code, it will cause your axes to become of equal length (in pixels). Now your surface looks like a sphere!

Comment: i have used _axis equal_. but i looks like sphere only for some values of isovalues.

Comment: @Wouster Kuijsters thanks. i have used  `axis equal` for some isovalues it looks like sphere but not for other values.  may be shape of plot also depends on isovalue which i used.

Comment: @YugeshEgala For sure all isovalue below `exp(-1)` will not look like a sphere, but portions of it (because they are beyond sphere of radius 1.0 which is the side of your cube) ... and you will plot nothing below `exp(-3)` ... it's quite unclear what you were expecting ?